# Common chemcials that produce phosphorescence

Tags: spectrophotometry, fluorescence, phosphorescence

Are there any common lab chemicals or household stuff that produce phosphorescence?

I am aware of ZnS, CaS, Fluorescein, Erythrosin B, Vanillin Benzaldehyde, Vitamin B2, Tryptophan etc.

I just need something for sanity check on a fluorescence/phosphorecence lifetime measurement system. I am getting results with fluorescence, but not with phosphorescence.

My samples are biological plant material. With TCSPC in nano second timescale, I am getting fluorescence decay. But with micro and milli second timescale, I am getting only unifom constant counts (looking like background counts). The sanity check is to see if the instrument is able to detect phosphorescence decay from any material known to have phosphorescence, hence the question.

#### Counts with Nano second timescale

[image: Counts with Nano second timescale]

#### Counts with Milli second timescale (Red = IRF, Black = Decay)

[image: Counts with Milli second timescale]

Comment: There are plenty of “glow in the dark” phosphorescent things you could try, e.g., the phosphorescent stars some people put on their kid’s bedroom ceilings. You can easily find phosphorescent tape online and likewise various colors of phosphorescent paints.

Comment: It is a commercial system -  Horiba DeltaPro. Excitation is with DeltaDiode Pulsed laser 375 nm. Detection is with PPD-650 (230-700 nm range). Timing electronics is DeltaHub-HT (25 ps to 1s lifetimes). Using a sample holder with front face orientation at an off-45 degree angle. In addition there is a long pass filter with 395 nm cut-on to negate scatter.

Comment: Thanks, very nice system from what you say. So it is puzzling that you are “not getting results” with phosphorescence. The list of chemicals you gave does not suggest room temperature phosphorescence will be observed with them, particularly if oxygen, even at very low concentration, is present. Freeze-pump-thaw deoxygenation might do the trick (this is standard practice), but I would personally just use a phosphorescent tape or sheet.

Comment: Phosphorescence in organic materials is hard to measure unless the solvent has had *all* the oxygen removed as this is a very efficient quencher, as are heavy atoms/ions such as iodide. Thus you need to  freeze-pump-thaw on a vacuum line with liq Nitrogen, or purge with O2 free nitrogen or argon and seal the cell completely, vacuum taps etc.   Fluorescence lifetimes are best measured by time correlated single photon counting on nanosecond timescale  (many commercial systems exist),  phosphorescence is very  slow (microsecond and longer) that a laser and scope are easily fast enough.

Comment: My samples are biological plant material. With TCSPC in nano second timescale, I am getting fluorescence decay. But with micro and milli second timescale, I am getting only unifom constant counts (looking like background counts). The sanity check is to see if the instrument is able to detect phosphorescence decay from any material known to have phosphorescence, hence the question.

Comment: @Crops, I copied your main question from comments to the main question, otherwise random people will keep down voting an otherwise useful query.

Comment: @Crops, Could you also add the TCSPC of the blank solution? Secondly, why are you assuming that you would have phosphorescence at *room temperature* in the presence of air and in solution? It is a rare phenomenon.

Comment: It is not a solution. These are solid samples placed at front-face orientation with an off 45 degree angle.

Comment: Instead of TCSPC of blank solution, I have added the one from the Ludox solution, which is used as the IRF. 10000 is the preset peak, ie. the counts are read until the no. of counts in the largest bin reaches the preset value. I will try again with the maximum timescale (1s) possible with the machine.

Comment: I'm not surprised that you are getting a constant background on such a long time scale, just thermal noise will give this even with a cooled detector. Are you running the source at only 100/sec otherwise a bit of scattered light and /or or fluorescence  from this might be giving your signal. Was the long time signal with a blank of with a sample? As you use plant material this article  which shows weak, time independent, chlorophyll chemiluminescence (observed by tcspc) may be interesting  Beddard et al. Nature, vol 267, p373,1977.

Comment: @porphyrin, How come the background reading is constant at 1000? The fluorescence decay also starts from 1000.

Comment: @M Farooq There could be lots of reasons, we do not know what the experimental conditions are. If the light source reprate is MHz then this could just be fluorescence or scattering.

Comment: Try a white LED; some phosphors have half-lives in the multi-millisecond range.

Comment: Uranyl ion has a fluorescence lifetime of about 1.5 microseconds: Catalysis of ionic reactions by polyelectrolytes. III. Quenching of uranyl ion fluorescence by iron(II) ions in poly(vinylsulfonic acid) solution, Herbert MorawetzIssam A. I. Taha, J. Am. Chem. Soc. 1971, 93, 4, 829-833 Publication Date:February 1, 1971 doi.org/10.1021/ja00733a005. Uranium glass, sometimes called ‘vaseline glass’, is easily available in university glass shops and on eBay. Not phosphorescence, but relative long lived fluorescence and very convenient to use. Also, Amazon and Home Depot sell phosphorescent paint.